# How to generate a static Django JavaScript translation catalog

Tags: javascript, python, django, internationalization, translation

Doing translation in JavaScript in Django apps is covered in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code) quite well. However, the built-in Django way is to load a JS file in a `<script>`. Of course, they suggest to cache this, but one either needs to use etags or another mechanism and it will normally add at least one more request to the page load.

However, most decent websites already have a build system for preparing static files, i.e. using gulp - for compiling SCSS, sprites and whatnot. This is the perfect place to build a JS translation catalog, concatenate it with the rest of the JS and make 1 single bundled JS file. There doesn't seem to be way to generate a static JS file from the current *.mo files. Reading through the Django code, it seems that the JavaScriptCatalog view is responsible for generating that JS code and it's not easily reusable for that purpose either.

TL;DR Is there an easy way to generate a static .js file with the current translation catalog in a fashion similar to using the built-in JavaScriptCatalog?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/zyegfryed/django-statici18n which I think does what you're asking for. Note however, that there will be one javascript catalog file per supported language, and you must serve only one of them to the browser. So to make "1 single bundled JS file" means making one bundled file per language.